# Returning employee balances

Tags: vb.net, windows

Here is the code for balance retrieval from EMPLOYEES record. Please simplify and improve it accordingly. It is working fine and I have no problem with it but I believe that's not the correct way to do it.

```
Public Sub GET_BALANCE_VALUE(EMPLOYEE_ID As Integer, EMPLOYEE_NAME As String, ByRef BALANCE As Integer)
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user=root; password=Masoom1; database=airtech_db; convert zero datetime=true;")
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    Dim DR As MySqlDataReader
    Dim DB_BAL_RETRIVAL As Integer
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

'TO GET PREVIOUS BALANCE
SQL_CMD_TXT = "SELECT * FROM `employees`" & " WHERE `NAME`= '" &
UCase(EMPLOYEE_NAME) & "' AND `EMPLOYEE_ID`= '" &
EMPLOYEE_ID & "';"
Try
    con.Open()
    sql = SQL_CMD_TXT
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
    DR = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While DR.Read = True
        DB_REC_VALUE = DR("NAME").ToString()
        DB_ID_VALUE = DR("EMPLOYEE_ID")
        DB_BAL_RETRIVAL = DR("BALANCE")
    Loop
        End If
    con.Close()
Catch ex As MySqlException
    Dim mbe = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SALARY_HISTORY_MOD Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try

'RETURNING BALANCE VALUE
BALANCE = DB_BAL_RETRIVAL
End Sub`
```

Comment: I don't see much of complication in that code that could be simplified.

Comment: There is an "end if" statement but I don't see the if? And you are looping but expect only one record and you use only one of the values? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Well, You don't really need to retrieve `DB_REC_VALUE` and `DB_ID_VALUE`. As what I understand from your code there should be exactly one record returned from the query, so you could just omit the loop and just check if there's exactly one row as result.

Comment: YES hafner you get it right thats whats i was thinking too so

Comment: `[that's what I] was thinking too` [Are you an author or maintainer of this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), in a position to place it [under Creative Commons](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two things that can be done:

- prettify the code
- use **parameterized queries**: this is important from a security point of view but also for functional reasons (escaping values that contain single quotes and will break your SQL)

I don't know how your DB is structured but in a properly designed DB the employee ID should be a unique (incremented ?) identifier and sufficient in itself. `Name` is a reserved keyword in many languages and it is generally discouraged. But that shouldn't cause problems here since it's enclosed within backticks.

Here is some proposed code that returns the balance as integer value. I don't really think you are interested in the other variables since you already know them. But you could return a datarow if you want to fetch several values in one pass.

---

```
Public Class frmDemo

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim balance As Integer
        balance = GetBalanceValue(EmployeeID:=2, EmployeeName:="Jonas")
        MessageBox.Show("Balance: " & balance.ToString)

    End Sub

    Public Function GetBalanceValue(ByVal EmployeeID As Integer, ByVal EmployeeName As String) As Integer
        Dim balance As Integer
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT BALANCE FROM `employees`" & _
        " WHERE `NAME`= @employee_name" & _
        " AND `EMPLOYEE_ID`= @employee_id"

        Try
            Using con As New MySqlConnection("connection string goes here")
                con.Open()
                If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then ' connection successful, continue

                    Using cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
                        With cmd
                            .Parameters.Add("@employee_id", DbType.Int32).Value = EmployeeID
                            .Parameters.Add("@employee_name", DbType.String).Value = UCase(EmployeeName)

                            ' retrieve the first value found
                            balance = Convert.ToInt32(.ExecuteScalar())
                            Return balance
                        End With
                    End Using

                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection failure", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                    Return Nothing
                End If

            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Function

End Class
```

---

So the idea here is to use a function to retrieve the balance for a given employee. The error handling is a bit crap - this is for demonstration purposes.

- I tested the code with a SQLite DB but the proposed code should be ok or almost ok for you
- You will notice the use of the **Using** statement. If you are working with files, database connections or other kinds of unmanaged resources you will often use it. Intro: [Using Statement (Visual Basic).](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement)
- I am using `ExecuteScalar` to retrieve one single field from the first row found (normally there should be only one row per employee). Warning: this will cause an error if no row is found. If you anticipate this situation you have to adapt the logic a bit. An alternative approach is to load the results to a datatable and check that you have at least one datarow.
- Since you are using **Mysql**, perhaps you will have to remove the `@` in front of the parameter names, for some databases (Oracle) the norm is to use a colon instead. If the parameterized queries don't work immediately for you don't despair but investigate. The sooner you adopt best practices the better.
- consistency: your table name is lower case and field names are uppercase. Use lower case everywhere
- you can use the underscore character (`_`) to separate keywords in object names eg `employeee_id`
- avoid generic/**reserved keywords**, they can cause problems that are not always obvious and sometimes hard to debug
- exception handling: normally you will handle Mysql exceptions only in this block, for all other exceptions you should have a module-level handler

Suggestion: the next time you post public code, remove the password and other sensitive information.

Comment: Great answer. But wouldn't you have to change the query from returning * to returning the balance in the select?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You could change to ExecuteScalar function if you only expect one record. The difference between your code and mine would be in case there are more than one records you take the last record and this code takes the first record.
I also removed the "end if" statement as I don't know what it was for.
Mind that I also changed the select statement to only return the balance as you are not using the name and employee id:

```
Public Sub GET_BALANCE_VALUE(EMPLOYEE_ID As Integer, EMPLOYEE_NAME As String, ByRef BALANCE As Integer)
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user=rrrr; password=dddd; database=airtech_db; convert zero datetime=true;")
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    Dim DR As MySqlDataReader
    Dim DB_BAL_RETRIVAL As Integer
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

'TO GET PREVIOUS BALANCE - only selects column BALANCE.
SQL_CMD_TXT = "SELECT BALANCE FROM `employees`" & " WHERE `NAME`= '" &
UCase(EMPLOYEE_NAME) & "' AND `EMPLOYEE_ID`= '" &
EMPLOYEE_ID & "';"
Try
    con.Open()
    sql = SQL_CMD_TXT
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
    DB_BAL_RETRIVAL = (integer)cmd.ExecuteScalar() ' returns  null if nothing found
    con.Close()
Catch ex As MySqlException
    Dim mbe = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SALARY_HISTORY_MOD Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try

'RETURNING BALANCE VALUE
BALANCE = DB_BAL_RETRIVAL
End Sub`
```